# Iptables log clent IP to file

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, port

Im trying to track whether some ports are being used, and what by, as I want to close them. I have made some iptables traffic counters, and have worked out is a small amount of traffic, coming into a java prcess. Now i want to know what is consuming it. How can I get iptables to log the IP of the client (to syslog or similar) ?

Comment: I have an example of iptables logging NEW connections here http://serverfault.com/questions/446800/iptables-logging-doesnt-log/446809#446809

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- check connections with `netstat -anp`
- install [wireshark](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/) / [tshark](http://www.chrisbrenton.org/2009/10/analyzing-packets-with-tshark/) / [tcpdump](http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/) analyzers and filter for packets for specific ports (recommended)
- [use LOG action for iptables rules to log specific packets](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1158091)

Comment: RE: Option # 3, would this work? - iptables -A jmx-debug -p tcp --dport 8084 -j LOG --log-prefix ' JMXDEBUG ' --log-level 4 && iptables -A jmx-debug -p tcp --sport 8084 -j LOG --log-prefix ' JMXDEBUG ' --log-level 4 && iptables-save

Comment: -A must be followed by OUTPUT, or INPUT, rest is fine.

Comment: just use tcpdump

Comment: http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/

Comment: Id rather not TCPdump it. The box has 4 10ge cards bonded. The dump would be colossal. Anyway, seems to be only traffic on the loopback device, im gonna close the ports.

Comment: @bsg75 - though the iptables LOG action is your best option here, you should know that you **can** pass tcpdump filters so that it only dumps traffic that matches specifically what you're looking for. Additionally, you can also limit the number of bytes captured, so you only get the TCP/IP headers.